# Putting a MySQL installing system to git

Tags: git

I have never used git but now I need to use it as I'm trying to install Drupal. I installed MySQL, created user and gave permissions to user. Now, how can I put that database to git? I just want to take a backup of my database in the case of something goes wrong.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/856160 or http://drupal.org/project/dbscripts could help. Putting a dump of the MySQL database into a VCS isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm i think in this case git is not the right. When you want a backup you can use a master - slave replication.

With git your data is save when you make a git add and commit and push. In this case you have to do this process everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Make a script?

```
pushd /path/to/repo
mysqldump --all-databases > db.sql
git add db.sql
git commit -m "Snapshot as of `date '+%Y-%m-%d'`"
git push
popd
```

I'm a way bigger fan of ZFS though. I completely agree with Stony's answer here, but if you really want to pump it to git, that's how you'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL, ZFS and ZRM (Amanda) to do efficient snapshots... You can always add a export to tar option from a given point in time copy and remove the snapshot, for instance!.

Note that ZFS does run on Linux (Lawrence Livermore's modules), so if you're really looking for space and time efficient snapshotting, this is it!

Technically, one reason you need ZRM is so you can "freeze" DB operations for a second and have a consistent in-disk copy.

Comment: I'm a bit afraid that mysql might be in the middle of dumping a transaction if he uses ZFS. I'm a massive fan of ZFS either way.

Comment: Well, you can always go the path of running 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK' and then use snapshots, then 'UNLOCK TABLES' to launch.

Comment: You sir, know far more about MySQL than I :D